# How to insert data at specific levels in MongoDB document?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553e0c2ec9ad2dbe13cc17cc"),
    "country" : "ireland",
    "games" : [
            {
                    "title" : "Test",
                    "draws" : [ ]
            },
            {
                    "title" : "Test 2",
                    "draws" : [ ]
            },
            {
                    "title" : "Test 3",
                    "draws" : [ ]
            }
    ]
}
```

I want to store multiple objects of the same structure under the **draws** key. Right now, if I want to return the **Test** game, I would execute the following Mongo query:

```
db.data.find({country:"ireland"},{games:{$elemMatch:{title:"Test"}}})
```

...which returns:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553e0c2ec9ad2dbe13cc17cc"),
    "games" : [
            {
                    "title" : "Test",
                    "draws" : [ ]
            }
    ]
}
```

How can I enter data into the **draws** key? Here's an example of what I'm looking to achieve:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553e0c2ec9ad2dbe13cc17cc"),
    "country" : "ireland",
    "games" : [
            {
                    "title" : "Test",
                    "draws" : [{
                        "date":"20150207",
                        "numbers":[10,20,30,40,50,60]
                    },
                    {
                        "date":"20150214",
                        "numbers":[09,07,22,31,39,30]
                    },
                    {
                        "date":"20150221",
                        "numbers":[11,07,22,13,30,01]
                    }]
            },
            {
                    "title" : "Test 2",
                    draws : [{
                        "date":"20150207",
                        "numbers":[03,08,21,19,24,01]
                    },
                    {
                        "date":"20150214",
                        "numbers":[19,17,02,11,19,32]
                    },
                    {
                        "date":"20150221",
                        "numbers":[31,27,12,10,15,11]
                    }]
            },
            {
                    "title" : "Test 3",
                    draws : [{
                        "date":"20150207",
                        "numbers":[10,17,29,33,31,11]
                    },
                    {
                        "date":"20150214",
                        "numbers":[12,17,19,33,31,02]
                    },
                    {
                        "date":"20150221",
                        "numbers":[01,17,32,23,31,01]
                    }]
            }
    ]
}
```

I have tried **update()** with **upsert** but it kept writing a new document every time.

Comment: If you want to add every `title` with different `draws` array values then using mongo single update query is not possible, you should iterate over `games` array and then add values in draws. For more help [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498872/how-to-change-datatype-of-netsted-field-in-mongo-document)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @yogesh. I had the wrong format in my desired JSON. If you could see the update above, that is what I am looking to get.

Comment: This looks like same as your previous output, this case if you know `games.title:Test` then you should add `draws` array of `title:Test`. So adding three `draws` you should be use three different query for updating single document. So better way to use some programming coding or use mongo `bulk` operations

Comment: So what you're saying is that I can't update/add to `games.draws` (even if I know `games.title`) using `db.**collection**.update()` out of the box?

Comment: Yes, if you know the `games.title` then you should easily add `draws` array of given values.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to insert a sub document.

```
db.data.update({country:"ireland",games:{$elemMatch:{title:"Test"}}}, 
       {
           $push: {
               'games.$.draws': [

               {"date":"20150207",
                "numbers":[10,20,30,40,50,60]}


               ]}

           })
```

It resulted in the following.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553e2a32f077cac2cbb9a033"),
    "country" : "ireland",
    "games" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "Test",
            "draws" : [ 
                [ 
                    {
                        "date" : "20150207",
                        "numbers" : [ 
                            10, 
                            20, 
                            30, 
                            40, 
                            50, 
                            60
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "Test 2",
            "draws" : []
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "Test 3",
            "draws" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is not valid answers, check question and comments