# implementing mongodb query in java using java mongo driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am using the below mongo query to get the max temperature.  Can any one help how to implement in java using mongo java driver using  `BasicDBObject` and `DBObject`?

```
db.EventLog.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$_id",
           maxInnerTemp: { $max: { $concat : [ "0", "$fields.innerTemp"]}}
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mongo java aggregation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/) like below code ( not tested ) :

```
 // $group operation
 BasicDBList concat = new BasicDBList();
 concat.add("0");
 concat.add("$fields.innerTemp");
 DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$_id");
 groupFields.put("maxInnerTemp", new BasicDBObject("$max", new BasicDBObject("$concat", concat)); 
 DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
     // run aggregation
     List < DBObject > pipeline = Arrays.asList(group); AggregationOutput output = collectionName.aggregate(pipeline);
     for (DBObject result: output.results()) {
       System.out.println(result);
     }
```

Comment: thq so much it helped me a lot

Comment: how can i find the min and max of a field of string type with out using iteration

Comment: first convert string data type to `Number` and then try to implement using any simple java method to find min and max.

Comment: thq as per requirement it should be  string and no iterations (due to large amount of data) any possible way to find out min ,max , avg

Comment: this case you should changed your documents values string to number using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498872/how-to-change-datatype-of-netsted-field-in-mongo-document) and then used mongo [Accumulator Operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)

Comment: thq groupFields.put("min_inner", new BasicDBObject( "$min", "$fields.innerTemp")); i am using the above format for getting min can help me how to use that parsefloat in this case (i am using collection.aggregate() function )