# document is stored with int instead of double

Tags: mongodb

I am inserting a document into the mongodb theat looks like this:

```
{"Name":"Some Name","Value" : 1, "Value2" : 1.2, ...}
```

Value will be stored as Datatype int32 and Value2 as Datatype double. I am storing the whole document in one string (`db.table.insertmany("[mydocument]");`)

Can I use some functions like `NumberLong(...)` for doubles? Is there anything like that?
I saw another question on stack: [MongoDb - Change type from Int to Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265079/mongodb-change-type-from-int-to-double?noredirect=1&lq=1)
But I can not reproduce the case that the number is default stored as double. Is there a database setting or something for the default datatype?

Comment: Types supported by mongodb: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html That's how you can use it in mongo shell: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/index.html

Answer (score -1):

The mongo shell treats all numbers as 64-bit floating-point double values by default.

For more info https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/

Comment: I can not reproduce that - the inserted document in my mongo compass is marked as 32-bit integer. (Value)
to be more precisly... The document is inserted with the method input of type `string`.