# MongoDB - Update data type of field

Tags: mongodb

The data got inserted as below.

{"key1": 20.05, "key2": 21.24 }

It was expected to be stored as Double, but the value was stored as String and when the document was returned, the value was,

{"key1": "20.05", "key2": "21.24" }

Is there anyway to update the data type to double without scanning each document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note**

By default, all `numbers` are stored as `double` in MongoDB unless generally cast overwise.

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/31267615/10861398

---

**MongoDB version 4.2 above**

You can update the type data of the field with aggregation. Below is an example of an aggregate query to change the data type in the `$key2` field to `double`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      key2: { $toDouble: '$key2' },
    },
  },
])
```

> if the data to be converted to `double` cannot be altered (ex: "4Bn"), an error will occur. To prevent this, you can use an additional operator called [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#exp._S_convert).

**Reference:** [$toDouble](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/)

---

**MongoDB version 3.2 above**

MongoDB does not yet support operator `$set` in aggregation in this version. So you have to do it manually with `find`, `forEach`, and `updateOne`.

**Example using `mongo` shell:**

```js
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function (doc) {
  db.collection.updateOne(
    {
      _id: doc._id,
    },
    {
      $set: {
        key2: NumberInt(doc.key2),
      },
    }
  )
})
```

**Reference:** [NumberInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberint)

Comment: Will it scan the entire documents? Will it trigger oplog events for each document update?

Comment: All operations that change data will be recorded in oplog. While there is no other way to change the data type of a field except to change its value.

Comment: This is not working for MongoDB version 4.0. "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'",

Comment: Yeah. Aggregatetion `$set` is available in MongoDB version 4.2. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#definition

Comment: I have added an answer for the old version.