# When trying to cast big number to double I get int (scala)

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

Im receiving from outside of my scala service an json that include a certain field with a number, for instance `23945616`, and in my model this field is `amount: Option[Double]`, but what actually get inserted to the db is is `23945616` as an int32 but I expect double...

If I manually change it to be double in mongo it will work, but why certain big numbers do that?

the steps:

first im receiving the object from sqs as BigDecimal:

```
case class Amount(value: BigDecimal, currency: String)
```

then im mapping it to be my own model which this field is type double:
my model:

```
case class Expense(....
                          transactionAmount: Option[Double],
                          currency: Option[String]
                          ....
)
```

then im inserting to mongodb (using reactivemongo):

```
  def insertExpenses(report: Report, expenses: List[Expense]): Future[Report] = {
    collection.findAndUpdate(
      selector = Json.obj(s"${ReportFields.id}" -> report._id),
      update = Json.obj("$set" -> Json.obj(s"${ReportFields.Expenses}" -> expenses)),
      fetchNewObject = true, upsert = false, sort = None, fields = None, bypassDocumentValidation = false, writeConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged, maxTime = None, collation = None, arrayFilters = Nil)
      .map(_.result[Report].getOrElse {
        logger.error(s"Failed to insert expenses, report._id: ${report._id}")
        throw new NoSuchElementException(s"Failed to update insert expenses value")
      })
  }
```

Comment: Do you think `23945616 > (2^31 -1)` ?

Comment: Can you please paste the schema of your db & also are you especially type casting it. As i understand, in MongoDB by default all "numbers" are stored as "double" iunless generally cast overwise. See if this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/31267615/5801823

Comment: @papaya im actually receiving it as BigDecimal from the api, but then transform it to my model which is Double, and only after that im saving to mongo...this is why it happens, but why cant I change it from BigDecimal to Double inside my app?

Comment: Please share the schema & piece of code you use to insert to db.

Comment: @papaya done, just updated the question with the flow

Comment: @JohnBigs are you getting an implicit numeric warning? Should show up, if you are using an IDE

Comment: its unclear from your question if you are successfully coverting a BigDecimal into a Double in scala and just having trouble when the value is inserted into Mongodb or you are having trouble with the conversion

Comment: Why using JSON serialization for that? Also throwing exception (even if there it's caught) is not recommended