# Retrieve an array of specific elements from mongoDB document

Tags: mongodb

Below is a mongoDB document, which contains an items field which is an array of documents (of similar object type)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ef38cc426e994a8590fce8"),
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "drId" : "55ef34d3426eee33f626efc5",
            "duration" : {
                "value" : "1",
                "durationUnit" : {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "unit" : "Week",
                    "dId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0f9b",
                    "lId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0fa1",
                    "hId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0fa0"
                }
            },
            "dos" : "1-1-1",
            "direction" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "direction" : "Test Direction",
                    "dId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0f9b",
                    "lId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0fa1",
                    "hId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0fa0"
                }
            ],
            "instructions" : "Test Instructions"
        },
    {
            "drId" : "55ef34d3426eee33f626efc6",
            "duration" : {
                "value" : "1",
                "durationUnit" : {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "unit" : "Week",
                    "dId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0f9b",
                    "lId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0fa1",
                    "hId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0fa0"
                }
            },
            "dos" : "1-1-1",
            "direction" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "direction" : "Test Direction",
                    "dId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0f9b",
                    "lId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0fa1",
                    "hId" : "55edf013426eb4845f2e0fa0"
                }
            ],
            "instructions" : "Test Instructions"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to retrieve an array of only drId's (in case of the document above)

For eg. the result should be

```
["55ef34d3426eee33f626efc5", "55ef34d3426eee33f626efc6"]
```

Can this be achieved in mongoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out this using [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) as below :

```
db.collection.distinct("items.drId")
```

Or with the help of aggregation with [$map](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) as below :

```
db.collection.aggregate({"$project":{"drId":{"$map":{"input":"$items","as":"el","in":"$$el.drId"}},"_id":0}})
```

Comment: can you also tell how to retrieve only from documents where _id matches to a specific value

Comment: I think probably you asking about **[$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)**

Comment: Is there any way to convert data types while retrieving data from mongo, for eg: what will I need to do if want my array of drIds(String) as array if drIds(ObjectId or oid)

Comment: this is not possible directly using mongo query, you should used some programming code to convert to `string` to `objectId`, for this you should used  **[mongo bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/bulk-write-operations/)** and for ref. example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498872/how-to-change-datatype-of-netsted-field-in-mongo-document)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$items"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "drIds": {
                "$push": "$items.drId"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "drIds": 1
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "drIds" : [ 
                "55ef34d3426eee33f626efc5", 
                "55ef34d3426eee33f626efc6"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```